# Keras variable length input for regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, variable-length-array

Everyone!

I am trying to develop a neural network using Keras and TensorFlow, which should be able to take variable length arrays as input and give either some single value (see the toy example below) or classify them (that a problem for later and will not be touched in this question).

The idea is fairly simple.

We have variable length arrays. I am currently using very simple toy data, which is generated by the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras import models as kem
from keras import activations as kea
from keras import layers as kel
from keras import regularizers as ker
from keras import optimizers as keo
from keras import losses as kelo
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import  normalize

n = 100
x = pd.DataFrame(columns=['data','res'])

mms = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))


for i in range(n):
    k = np.random.randint(20,100)
    ss = np.random.randint(0,100,size=k)
    idres = np.sum(ss[np.arange(0,k,2)])-np.sum(ss[np.arange(1,k,2)])
    x.loc[i,'data'] = ss
    x.loc[i,'res'] = idres

x.res = mms.fit_transform(x.res)

x_train,x_test,y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x.data,x.res,test_size=0.2)
x_train = sliding_window(x_train.as_matrix(),2,2)
x_test = sliding_window(x_test.as_matrix(),2,2)
```

To put it simple, I generate arrays with random length and the result (output) for each array is sum of even elements - sum of odd elements. Obviously, it can be negative and positive. The output then scaled to the range [-1,1] to fit with `tanh` activation function.

The Sequential model is generated as following:

```
model = kem.Sequential()

model.add(kel.LSTM(20,return_sequences=False,input_shape=(None,2),recurrent_activation='tanh'))
model.add(kel.Dense(20,activation='tanh'))
model.add(kel.Dense(10,activation='tanh'))
model.add(kel.Dense(5,activation='tanh'))
model.add(kel.Dense(1,activation='tanh'))

sgd = keo.SGD(lr=0.1)
mseloss = kelo.mean_squared_error
model.compile(optimizer=sgd,loss=mseloss,metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And the training of the model is doing in the following way:

```
def calcMSE(model,x_test,y_test):
    nTest = len(x_test)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(nTest):
        restest = model.predict(np.reshape(x_test[i],(1,-1,2)))
        sum+=(restest-y_test[0,i])**2
    return sum/nTest

i = 1
mse = calcMSE(model,x_test,np.reshape(y_test.values,(1,-1)))
lrPar = 0
lrSteps = 30
while mse>0.04:
    print("Epoch %i" % (i))
    print(mse)
    for j in range(len(x_train)):
        ntrain=j
        model.train_on_batch(np.reshape(x_train[ntrain],(1,-1,2)),np.reshape(y_train.values[ntrain],(-1,1)))

    i+=1
    mse = calcMSE(model,x_test,np.reshape(y_test.values,(1,-1)))
```

The problem is that optimiser gets stuck usually around MSE=0.05 (on test set). Last time I tested, it actually stuck around MSE=0.12 (on test data).

Moreover, if you will look at what the model gives on test data (left column) in comparison with the correct output (right column):

```
[[-0.11888303]] 0.574923547401
[[-0.17038491]] -0.452599388379
[[-0.20098214]] 0.065749235474
[[-0.22307695]] -0.437308868502
[[-0.2218809]] 0.371559633028
[[-0.2218741]] 0.039755351682
[[-0.22247596]] -0.434250764526
[[-0.17094387]] -0.151376146789
[[-0.17089397]] -0.175840978593
[[-0.16988073]] 0.025993883792
[[-0.16984619]] -0.117737003058
[[-0.17087571]] -0.515290519878
[[-0.21933308]] -0.366972477064
[[-0.09379648]] -0.178899082569
[[-0.17016701]] -0.333333333333
[[-0.17022927]] -0.195718654434
[[-0.11681376]] 0.452599388379
[[-0.21438009]] 0.224770642202
[[-0.12475857]] 0.151376146789
[[-0.2225963]] -0.380733944954
```

And on training set the same is:

```
[[-0.22209576]] -0.00764525993884
[[-0.17096499]] -0.247706422018
[[-0.22228305]] 0.276758409786
[[-0.16986915]] 0.340978593272
[[-0.16994311]] -0.233944954128
[[-0.22131597]] -0.345565749235
[[-0.17088912]] -0.145259938838
[[-0.22250554]] -0.792048929664
[[-0.17097935]] 0.119266055046
[[-0.17087702]] -0.2874617737
[[-0.1167363]] -0.0045871559633
[[-0.08695849]] 0.159021406728
[[-0.17082921]] 0.374617737003
[[-0.15422876]] -0.110091743119
[[-0.22185338]] -0.7125382263
[[-0.17069265]] -0.678899082569
[[-0.16963181]] -0.00611620795107
[[-0.17089556]] -0.249235474006
[[-0.17073657]] -0.414373088685
[[-0.17089497]] -0.351681957187
[[-0.17138508]] -0.0917431192661
[[-0.22351067]] 0.11620795107
[[-0.17079701]] -0.0795107033639
[[-0.22246087]] 0.22629969419
[[-0.17044055]] 1.0
[[-0.17090379]] -0.0902140672783
[[-0.23420531]] -0.0366972477064
[[-0.2155242]] 0.0366972477064
[[-0.22192241]] -0.675840978593
[[-0.22220723]] -0.354740061162
[[-0.1671907]] -0.10244648318
[[-0.22705412]] 0.0443425076453
[[-0.22943887]] -0.249235474006
[[-0.21681401]] 0.065749235474
[[-0.12495813]] 0.466360856269
[[-0.17085686]] 0.316513761468
[[-0.17092516]] 0.0275229357798
[[-0.17277785]] -0.325688073394
[[-0.22193027]] 0.139143730887
[[-0.17088208]] 0.422018348624
[[-0.17093034]] -0.0886850152905
[[-0.17091317]] -0.464831804281
[[-0.22241674]] -0.707951070336
[[-0.1735626]] -0.337920489297
[[-0.16984227]] 0.00764525993884
[[-0.16756304]] 0.515290519878
[[-0.22193302]] -0.414373088685
[[-0.22419722]] -0.351681957187
[[-0.11561158]] 0.17125382263
[[-0.16640976]] -0.321100917431
[[-0.21557514]] -0.313455657492
[[-0.22241823]] -0.117737003058
[[-0.22165506]] -0.646788990826
[[-0.22238114]] -0.261467889908
[[-0.1709189]] 0.0902140672783
[[-0.17698884]] -0.626911314985
[[-0.16984172]] 0.587155963303
[[-0.22226149]] -0.590214067278
[[-0.16950315]] -0.469418960245
[[-0.22180589]] -0.133027522936
[[-0.2224243]] -1.0
[[-0.22236891]] 0.152905198777
[[-0.17089345]] 0.435779816514
[[-0.17422611]] -0.233944954128
[[-0.17177556]] -0.324159021407
[[-0.21572633]] -0.347094801223
[[-0.21509495]] -0.646788990826
[[-0.17086846]] -0.34250764526
[[-0.17595944]] -0.496941896024
[[-0.16803505]] -0.382262996942
[[-0.16983894]] -0.348623853211
[[-0.17078683]] 0.363914373089
[[-0.21560851]] -0.186544342508
[[-0.22416025]] -0.374617737003
[[-0.1723443]] -0.186544342508
[[-0.16319042]] -0.0122324159021
[[-0.18837349]] -0.181957186544
[[-0.17371364]] -0.539755351682
[[-0.22232121]] -0.529051987768
[[-0.22187822]] -0.149847094801
```

As you can see, model output is actually all quite close to each other unlike the training set, where variability is much bigger (although, I should admit, that negative values are dominants in both training and test set.

What am I doing wrong here? Why training gets stuck or is it normal process and I should leave it for much longer (I was doing several hudreds epochs couple of times and still stay stuck). I also tried to use variable learning rate (used, for example, cosine annealing with restarts (as in I. Loshchilov and F. Hutter. Sgdr: Stochastic gradient descent with restarts.
arXiv preprint arXiv:1608.03983, 2016.)

I would appreciate any suggestions both from network structure and training approach and from coding/detailed sides.

Thank you very much in advance for help.

Comment: When the training set is good and the test set is not, it's very probably an "overfitting" case. Your model is powerful enough to "memorize" the training data in very specific details instead of detecting common patterns.

Comment: Common solutions for overfitting are "reduce the size" (capability) of your model. Or add "dropout" layers here and there.

Comment: I can try to use drop out, but because I am doing learning with the batch size of 1 (due to variable size of input), I suspect it will not work as intended.

Comment: Also, as you can see from the comparison of output and actual values on training set, the result for training set is no better than for test set, so, I have a suspicion that it is not overfitting, but rather some problems with learning process itself. Our probably the net structure itself is wrong.